# How to check whether file1 is a prefix of file2?

Tags: files, file-comparison

I have two files with sizes 124665 and 124858 in bytes and want to check whether file1 is a prefix of file2 or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Supposing you have the size of `file1` in the variable `FILE1_SZ` and your `head` implementation supports the (non-standard) `-c` option:

```
if head -c "$FILE1_SZ" file2 | cmp -s - file1; then
    echo "file1 is a prefix of file2"
else
    echo "file1 is not a prefix of file2"
fi
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Can you please explain why `cmp` would be better than `diff` here?

Comment: Because `cmp` does a simple byte to byte comparison, and returns as soon as it finds a difference, while `diff` is a text utility that is going to use a complex algorithm to show you all the differences between the two files which you don't care about.

Answer (score 12):

If your system has the `cmp` command from GNU `diffutils`, then one option is

```
cmp -n 124665 file1 file2
```

to compare at most the first 124665 bytes of the two files and report if they differ - or, more generally

```
cmp -n "$(wc -c < file1)" file1 file2
```

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I'm second guessing myself here but would it have been better to suggest `$(stat -c %s file1)` for the size in bytes? Does `wc` actually open and process the whole file to get the byte count?

Comment: no, most `wc` implementations will optimise that case and do a `fstat()` (or/and a `lseek(SEEK_END)`) so will be as efficient as it gets. On the other hand, that `stat -c` is GNU specific.

Comment: Although if you're going to require the GNU-specific `cmp`, you might reasonably assume GNU-specific `stat`.

Answer (score 3):

GNU `cmp` can solve the problem in an easier way:

```
cmp file1 file2
```

There are four possible outputs (barring some sort of error).

- No output: the files are identical.
- `cmp: EOF on file1`: file1 is a prefix of file2.
- `cmp: EOF on file2`: file2 is a prefix of file1.
- `file1 file2 differ: byte NNN, line MMM`: Neither is a prefix of the other.

Unfortunately this is a little awkward to use in a script, since these cases don't seem to be distinguished in the exit code.  Moreover, the `EOF on file1` messages go to stderr, while the `file1 file2 differ` message goes to stdout.

I presume that other versions of `cmp` do something similar, but I have not checked.

Comment: `cmp` is not a GNU-only command nor did it originate there, it was already in the first version of Unix in the early 70s. The `-n` option is GNU specific though.

Comment: You could do `cmp file1 file2 2>&1 | grep EOF on file1`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: That is true.  I didn't mean to imply that `cmp` was unique to GNU, just that GNU `cmp` was the only version I tried.  I added a sentence to clarify.

Comment: @DavidZ: Yes, you could, but it gets a little less robust.  Imagine that you are trying to do this with two files supplied by the user, and one of them is named `file1` and the other is named `file12`.  (Or worse yet, what if the second file is named `EOF on file1`?)  Solving this robustly using `cmp` is probably much more trouble than writing the obvious 5-line program in C...

Comment: There may be contexts where a C program isn't practical, though. And it's not that hard to make it fairly robust, because the output of `cmp` is so tightly constrained. Using the `-x` option on `grep` to match the entire line will take care of all but the most exotic cases (e.g. newlines in the filename).